# Repeat same data certain number of times

Tags: t-sql

I've ran into an issue that I cant seem to solve without a lot of changes deep in the code, and I think there must be a simpler solution that I'm simply not aware of.

I have a table of product names, product locations and various statuses (from 1 to 10). I have data for all products and locations but only some of the statuses (for example product X in city XX has data for categories 1 and 3, and product Y for city YY has data for categories 1 to 6).

I'd like to always display 10 repetitions of each product/location, with corresponding data (if there is any) or nulls. This makes a report I'm planning on creating much easier to read and understand.

I'm using SSMS2017, on SQL Server 2016.

```
SELECT 
[Product],
[Location],
[Category],
[Week1],
[Week2],
[Week3]
FROM MyView
```

Naturally it will only return data that I have, but I'd like to always return all 10 rows for each product/location combination (with nulls in Week columns if I have no data there).

Comment: Your question is a little confusing, and desired results would be helpful.  That said, I suspect you are looking for some sort of CROSS JOIN

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Do you have a table with all of the status values? Once we have the DDL and sample data it will be clearer, e.g. an `outer join` and `coalesce` may suffice to merge existing and "missing" data.

Comment: Sample data and your expected result would be a huge help.

Comment: Thanks - next time I'll make sure to provide sample data as well. My issue was solved now - a little CTE with numbers 1-10 and combination of cross/left joins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question ist not very clear, but I think, that my magic crystall ball gave me a good guess:

I think, that you are looking for `LEFT JOIN` and `CROSS JOIN`:

--Next time please create a *stand-alone* sample like this yourself
--I create 3 dummy tables with sample data

```
DECLARE @tblStatus TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,StatusName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tblStatus VALUES('Status 1')
                            ,('Status 2')
                            ,('Status 3')
                            ,('Status 4')
                            ,('Status 5');
DECLARE @tblGroup TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,GroupName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tblGroup VALUES ('Group 1')
                            ,('Group 2')
                            ,('Group 3')
                            ,('Group 4')
                            ,('Group 5');
DECLARE @tblProduct TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,ProductName VARCHAR(100),StatusID INT, GroupID INT);
INSERT INTO @tblProduct VALUES ('Product 1, Status 1, Group 2',1,2)
                              ,('Product 2, Status 1, Group 3',1,3)
                              ,('Product 3, Status 3, Group 4',3,4)
                              ,('Product 4, Status 3, Group 3',3,3)
                              ,('Product 5, Status 1, Group 5',1,5);
```

--This will return each status (independent of product values), together with the products (if there is a corresponding line)

```
SELECT s.StatusName
      ,p.*
FROM @tblStatus s
LEFT JOIN @tblProduct p ON s.ID=p.StatusID
```

--This will first use `CROSS JOIN` to create an *each-with-each* cartesian product.
--The `LEFT JOIN` works as above

```
SELECT s.StatusName
      ,g.GroupName
      ,p.*
FROM @tblStatus s
CROSS JOIN @tblGroup g
LEFT JOIN @tblProduct p ON s.ID=p.StatusID AND g.ID=p.GroupID;
```

If this is not what you need, please try to set up an example like mine and provide the expected output.

Comment: I suspect we will never know what the real question was.  Any case +1 for taking the time and the helpful hint at the end

Comment: On the contrary, @John, you will know :) This was what I needed pretty much, a workaround between two joins. 

I've ended up creating CTE with numbers from 1 to 10, cross joining it with distinct list of products and locations from my table and left joining to that construction the original table.

Thank you for your help Shnugo and next time I'll do my best to describe the question in more complex manner.

Comment: @DamianR Your question was more ambiguous than complex.  Providing sample data and desired results is essential, it eliminates false assumptions and "rabbit holes".  Had this question not caught Shnugo's eye  (of which I'm a huge fan), I suspect it would remained unanswered.   Cheers.